# primality and square freeness of the partition function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Divisibility properties of the partition function $p(n)$ seem to have been studied for the last three hundred years (most recently, Ken Ono has been quite active). However, I assume it is open that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $p(n)$ is prime. Is this true? Is there some conjecture about the density of such prime values? A similar question on the square-freeness of $p(n).$

Comment: In a 1992 paper, "Prime values of partition numbers and the primality of p(1840926)", Francois Morain gives a heuristic for the number of n<x for which p(n) is prime. Computer calculations for x< 10^6 suggest that the heuristic is plausible.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "three hundred years"? I always thought this story started in 1919 with Ramanujan's mod 5 and 7 congruences.

Comment: @user45130 I thought this all started with Euler (but, of course, I could be confused...)